# Permission problems in setuid-root program

Tags: c, permission-denied, pam, setuid

I have written a program, compiled it, copied it to /usr/local/bin/ and gave it setuid-root file permission.

Unfortunately, I cannot get the program to run as desired because of permission problems - that is, it runs well when I call it as a non-privileged user from the command line, but it throws errors when I call it as a non-privileged user from PAM module pam_exec - and that is the how I want to use it in the end.

So far, I had the following differences between calling it from the command line and calling it from pam_exec:

1. When I do not give the setuid-root file permission to the program, but give it the Linux cap_setuid capability instead, that works from the command line, but with pam_exec the program is not run at all, with error "Operation not permitted".
2. For further execution of the program, not only the effective, but also the real UID hast to be 0. From the command line, this works when I use setuid(0) in the program code, but with pam_exec, setuid(0) fails to change the real UID and I have to use setreuid(0,0) instead.
3. Though real and effective UID are 0, I still get errors like "Permission denied" and "Operation not permitted" when the program is called from pam_exec. First, this happened when executing external command lvcreate from my setuid-root program, and after I solved that now by using lvm dbus library calls instead, I even get an "Operation not permitted" when doing a simple chown() on a directory in the local filesystem. Of course, this all works perfectly when I start my program from the command line.

Any idea about possible reasons why a program with setuid-root file permission (or a program with special Linux capabilities), when it is called by an unprivileged user from PAM module pam_exec, behaves very different from when it is called by an unprivileged user from the command line? Or how it is possible at all that "Operation not permitted" and "Permission denied" errors occur though both getuid() and geteuid() return 0?

Regards
  Christoph

Comment: looks like some security module doesnt like your program, check systemd logs

Comment: @arash kordi: Do you mean something like SELinux or AppArmor? I had apparmor enabled before, but when first the problems with my program occurred, I disabled it - did not help.